# Mongodb returns error:The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of MongoError

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, express

Here is my long schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { conn } from '../config/connection'
import { ManagerModelInterface } from '../../types'
const managerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  analytics: {
    visits: {
      amounts: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
      },
      dates: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
      }
    }
  },
  disabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  verified: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  contracts: [{
    to: {
      type: String,
    },
    hash: {
      type: String
    },
    _id: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
      default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    },
    sended: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    contract: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    signedContract: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  }],
  notifications: [{
    _id: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      unique: true,
    },
    received: {
      type: Date,
      required: false,
      default: Date.now
    },
    from: {
      type: String
    },
    message: {
      type: String
    },
    readed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }],
  contacts: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      position: {
        type: String,
      },
      number: {
        type: String,
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  working_hours: {
    type: String,
  },
  adress: {
    type: String,
  },
  categories: {
    type: Array,
    default: [],
  },

  offices: [
    {

      _id: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        unique: true,
      },
      ips: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
        default: [],
      },
      owner: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      visible: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
      },
      verified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      description: {
        images: {
          type: Array,
          default: [],
        },
        images_webp: {
          type: Array,
          default: [],
        },
        ability_to_extend: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        floor: {
          type: String,
          default: '',
        },
        price: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        max_number_employees: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        parking_space_number: {
          type: String,
        },
        rooms: {
          type: String,
        },
        adress: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        unique_adress: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        visible_from_street: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        good_location: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },

        ramp: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        nearby: {
          type: String,
          default: '',
        },
        garage: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        larder: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        kv_m: {
          type: Number,
        },
        build_renovation_time: {
          type: Number,
        },
        heating_type: {
          type: String,
          default: '',
        },
        heading_costs: {
          type: String,
          default: '',
        },
        administrative_expenses: {
          type: String,
        },
        ventilation_and_condi: {
          type: String,
        },
        seperate_entrance: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        konference_room: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        kitchen: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        alarm_system: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        parking: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        many_passenger_by: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        internet: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        nice_view: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        energy_seritificate: {
          type: String,
        },
        modern_interior: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        much_light: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        terrace: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        meeting_room: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        steel_door: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        video_cameras: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        main_entrance_code: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        security_watchman: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        domofon: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        passing_cards: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        high_celling: {
          type: String,
        },
        private_wc: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        shared_wc: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        shower: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        no_furnitures: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        ability_change_interior: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        nice_to_have_neighborhood: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        resting_zone: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        pation: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
})

export default conn.model<ManagerModelInterface>('Manager', managerSchema)
```

And here is the method, which fires the error:

```
public saveManager(
    manager: NewManagerInterface
  ): Promise<ManagerModelInterface> {
    let newUser = new Manager(manager)
    console.log('saving account', newUser)
    return newUser.save()
  }
```

I have logged to console the manager object:

```
saving account {                                                                                                                                                   16:39:55
  analytics: {
    visits: {
      amounts: [],
      dates: []
    }
  },
  disabled: false,
  verified: false,
  categories: [],
  _id: 60f6d22b1eb00a3ecd2afc98,
  email: 'mvvvvp@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$jMzmdG.IzIjhhSEFKcTng.eTJk3Zz2uf4/iGW2DGZYwAw5AW/AkvG',
  name: 'Irmantas',
  offices: [],
  created: 2021-07-20T13:39:55.584Z,
  contracts: [],
  notifications: [],
  contacts: []
}
```

I was trying to figure out why I am getting this error with no success. Am I missing something? I use MongoDB. Is there any way to get a more specified error code why the code is not working?

Edited by adding the controller where the saveManager function is called. As you can see, the code didn't go through the saveManager method and returns an error.

```
class ManagerController {
  public async createManagerHandler(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ): Promise<Response> { 
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }

    let { email, password, name } = req.body

    // let manager = await managerService.findManagerByEmail(email)
    // if (manager)
    //   return res
    //     .status(409)
    //     .json(errorService.resError(['Manager with this email already exist']))
    try {
      let hashedPassword = await passwordService.hashPassword(password)
      let manager = await managerService.saveManager({
        email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        name,
        offices: [],
      })
      console.log('trying to create account', manager);
      let token = randomtoken(10)
      let verify = new Verify({
        ID: manager._id.toString(),
        token: token,
      })
      await verify.save()
      await emailService.sendEmail(
        `<p>Dear  ` +
        name +
        `, </p>
                  <p>Thanks for sign up. Your verification id and token is given below :  </p>
                 
                  <ul>
                      <li>User ID: ` +
        manager._id +
        `</li>
                      <li>Token: ` +
        token +
        `</li>
                  </ul>
                  <p>verify Link: <a href="http://localhost:3000/api/verifymanageraccount/${manager._id}/${token}">Verify</a></p>
                  
                  <p><strong>This is an automatically generated mail. Please do not reply back.</strong></p>
                  
                  <p>Regards,</p>
                  <p>H Manager</p>
              `,
        email,
        'Reigistration'
      )

      return res.status(200).json('Registered')
    } catch (err) {
      await errorService.writeErrorLog(err, 'createUserHandler')
      return res.status(500).json(errorService.criticalErr())
    }
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: please add how you are calling the ```saveManager``` function

Comment: can you try removing the ```next``` argument if you're not using it, I'm not sure it will work, but I understand that ```express``` can be specific with argument mapping

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ashwyn, but removing the next argument didn't help.